# How can you detect text entry throughout multiple sheets and manipulate cells below it?

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

I am trying to figure out how to add some cell values together from different sheets but I don't know what the cells references are as they vary!

Basically the values i need will appear 2 rows below some certain text. So I was looking for a formula that searches multiple sheets, finds the specific text, goes 2 rows below then adds the values together.

Comment: Yes it is possible. What have you tried? I suggest to do your task (or divide your question) into two phases: 1- getting the target cell in one worksheet, 2- generalizing to a sum from many worksheets.

Answer (score 3):

Here's something I hope you can adapt to your situation by changing the sheet and row and column range, the text to look for, and the destination of the total.

```
Sub findfvalues()
    Dim rowValue
    Dim total
    total = 0
    For r = 1 To 25 'update this to suit your needs
        For c = 1 To 25 'update this to suit your needs
            If Cells(r, c).Value = "f" Then 'update "f" to search for what you want
                rowValue = r + 2
                total = total + Cells(rowValue, c).Value
            End If
        Next
    Next
    Cells(30, 1).Value = total 'update this to suit your needs

End Sub
```

So we just check every cell for the "f" and if we find it, we add the value to a running total.  Display the total at the end.

Answer (score 0):

This will look in each worksheet, and if your text is found, add the value that's two rows below to a running total:

```
Sub find_Values()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim findStr As String
Dim foundCell As Range
Dim total As Long

findStr = "my Text"

For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    Set foundCell = ws.Cells.Find(what:=findStr)
    If Not foundCell Is Nothing Then
        total = total + foundCell.Offset(2, 0).Value
    End If
Next ws

Debug.Print "The value is: " & total

End Sub
```

Comment: @Chrisox - Did my answer, or JLH's solve your issue? If so, you can mark an answer as "The Answer", by clicking the check mark left of the post (under the up/down arrows).